# ASP.net: How i can limit the load of remote images based on image weight, dimensions & types?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image, image-processing

i've found this function for VB.net and i used in an .aspx page and works.

```
Private Sub LoadImageFromURL(URL As String, ByRef Img As Drawing.Bitmap)
    Const BYTESTOREAD As Integer = 10000
    Dim myRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)
    Dim myResponse As WebResponse = myRequest.GetResponse()
    Dim ReceiveStream As Stream = myResponse.GetResponseStream()
    Dim br As New BinaryReader(ReceiveStream)
    Dim memstream As New MemoryStream()
    Dim bytebuffer As Byte() = New Byte(BYTESTOREAD - 1) {}
    Dim BytesRead As Integer = br.Read(bytebuffer, 0, BYTESTOREAD)
    While BytesRead > 0
        memstream.Write(bytebuffer, 0, BytesRead)
        BytesRead = br.Read(bytebuffer, 0, BYTESTOREAD)
    End While
    Img = New Drawing.Bitmap(memstream)
End Sub
```

I would like to limit the loading of a remote imagebased on:

1) Image size limit in Bytes

2) Max Dimension of the pic x,y

3) Accepted image types (jpg, png)

I'm not so expert on image manipulation so I ask for a little help to improve the function if is possible and to enable some sort of protection on the image URL tio avoid malicious use.

EDIT: I must use the function on a .aspx page

Thanks

Comment: You can read the `content-type` and `content-length` headers and abort the operation if it's the wrong type or the length is too great.

Comment: thank for the hint, so i can use myResponse.ContentLength and myResponse.ContentType to read the values?. I never thought of this way :)

Comment: Also, if you set the `myRequest.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.Head`, it will only request the header info without starting any download.

Comment: that a new idea:) isp ossible to have a piece of code to test just to avoid any mix and error? :)

Answer (score 0):

I transformed into a function to validate the url and works.
Don't know if i can make it lighter and faster or if there is a better solution to do that.

```
Public Function ChkImageFromURL(URL As String) As Boolean
    Dim myRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)
    myRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Head
    Dim myResponse As WebResponse = myRequest.GetResponse()

    Dim ImageLen As Integer = myResponse.ContentLength
    Dim ImageType As String = myResponse.ContentType

    If ( Lcase(ImageType) <> "image/jpeg" AND Lcase(ImageType) <> "image/png" ) Or ImageLen > 300000 Then
        return false
    Else
        return true
    End if
End Function
```